# Uploading data into Mongolab database

Tags: c#, mlab

I am trying to insert elements into a MongoLab database (Sandbox plan) using C# (by parsing a xml file, but that is not the relevant part).

```
    var connectionString = "mongodb://user:pass@ds011111.mongolab.com:11111/db";
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("mydb");
        var elementCollection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(elementxml);
        XmlNodeList elementList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("element");
        foreach (XmlNode element in elementList) 
        {
            var t = new Entity();
            t.Name = element.FirstChild.InnerText;
            elementCollection.Insert(t); // this causes the error below
        }
```

This is the message I get:

```
WriteConcern detected an error 'not authorized for insert on mydb.entities'. (Response 
was { "err" : "not authorized for insert on mydb.entities", "code" : 16544, "n" : 0, 
"lastOp" : { "$timestamp" : NumberLong(0) }, "connectionId" : 33932414, "ok" : 1.0 }).
```

If I run the same code on localhost, everything works as intended

If I insert an element using mongo/shell I get `Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatability mode`, but it works

Does this mean I cannot populate my mongolab database with data (from C#) because I do not have the right permissions as a Sandbox user? If that is the case, what are my options?

Comment: Let's try eliminating variables.  Have you tried connecting with the mongo shell to confirm that you're using the correct credentials?  Can you confirm that you're using the correct database name both in your URI and in the call to GetDatabase()?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you're authenticating to the "db" database but trying to use the "mydb" database. Except for specially-privileged/admin users, most users only have access to one database, hence the `not authorized` error.  We run all our databases with authentication on, while the MongoDB defaults, which you're likely using locally, require no authentication; that's why you're not seeing the issue locally.

You should be grabbing the DB to be used from the URI. Here's an [example](https://github.com/mongolab/mongodb-driver-examples/blob/master/c%23/CSharpSimpleExample.cs#L58-L65) from our [Language Center](http://docs.mongolab.com/languages/).

```
  // Standard URI format: mongodb://[dbuser:dbpassword@]host:port/dbname

  String uri = "mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db";

  MongoUrl url = new MongoUrl(uri);
  MongoClient client = new MongoClient(url);
  MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
  MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase(url.DatabaseName);
```

If that doesn't sort you out, try our [connectivity troubleshooting guide](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#help). In particular, the next thing I'd look at is whether you're using the right credentials (see the section entitled "Check your database credentials").

Finally, please don't hesitate to contact us as support@mongolab.com if you continue to have issues or have any other questions.

Comment: Yes, the problem was actually caused by "var database = server.GetDatabase("mydb");". Switching the parameter to "db" fixes things (I access the existing database on mongolab instead of creating a new one - this was obviously not an issue on localhost, as it just created a new database). I will also try the solution above as it seems more elegant to me. Thank you very much!